# meaning of そんななか、

Tags: meaning, reading-comprehension

I read in [an article](http://www.asahi.com/articles/ASJ3J5SXZJ3JUTIL03M.html?iref=comtop_6_01) from the [Asahi Shimbun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asahi_Shimbun) :

> 学校{がっこう}で朝食{ちょうしょく}、おなかも心{こころ}も満{み}たす　高知{こうち}の小学校{しょうがっこう}
>
> 文部科学省{もんぶかがくしょう}が「早寝早起{はやねはやお}き朝{あさ}ごはん」国民{こくみん}運動{うんどう}を始{はじ}めて１０年{ねん}。だが近年{きんねん}、朝食{ちょうしょく}を食べない子{こ}の割合{わりあい}は増加{ぞうか}傾向{けいこう}だ。そんななか、子{こ}どもたちに朝食{ちょうしょく}を出{だ}している学校{がっこう}がある。

My translation (disclaimer : I'm not fluent at all in English, feel free to correct me)

> Breakfast at school : satisfy the stomach and the mind (elementary schools at Kōchi).
>
> 10 years ago began the national movement "a breakfast for the early to bed, early to rise children", a movement initiated by the Minister of Education. However in the last years, the percentage of children who don't eat breakfast is growing. XXX(that's why ???), some schools serve breakfast to the children.

What does "そんななか" mean ? Is it an [allegro form](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allegro%20form) for `そんな中` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This そんななか essentially is そのような状況の中で, and means "meanwhile", "against this background", etc.